# Selenium RC: Run tests in multiple browsers automatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, selenium, automated-tests

So, I've started to create some Ruby unit tests that use [Selenium RC](http://selenium-rc.openqa.org/) to test my web app directly in the browser.  I'm using the [Selenum-Client](http://github.com/ph7/selenium-client/tree/master) for ruby.  I've created a base class for all my other selenium tests to inherit from.

This creates numerous SeleniumDriver instances and all the methods that are missing are called on each instance.  This essentially runs the tests in parallel.

**How have other people automated this?**

This is my implementation:

```
class SeleniumTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def setup
    @seleniums = %w(*firefox *iexplore).map do |browser|
      puts 'creating browser ' + browser
      Selenium::SeleniumDriver.new("localhost", 4444, browser, "http://localhost:3003", 10000)
    end

    start
    open start_address
  end

  def teardown
      stop
  end

  #sub-classes should override this if they want to change it
  def start_address
    "http://localhost:3003/"
  end

  # Overrides standard "open" method
  def open(addr)
    method_missing 'open', addr
  end

  # Overrides standard "type" method
  def type(inputLocator, value)
    method_missing 'type', inputLocator, value
  end

  # Overrides standard "select" method
  def select(inputLocator, optionLocator)
    method_missing 'select', inputLocator, optionLocator
  end

  def method_missing(method_name, *args)
    @seleniums.each do |selenium_driver|
      if args.empty?
        selenium_driver.send method_name
      else
        selenium_driver.send method_name, *args
      end

    end
  end
end
```

This works, but if one browser fails, the whole test fails and there is no way to know which browser it failed on.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I have a similar question.  I was wondering if you can help. [Selenium RC:How to launch Interactive testing with Multiple browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2836313/selenium-rchow-to-launch-interactive-testing-with-multiple-browsers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try [Selenium Grid](http://selenium-grid.openqa.org/how_it_works.html)? I think it creates pretty good summary report which shows details you need. I may be wrong, as I didn't use it for quite a while.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up modifying Selenium's protocol.rb to raise an **`AssertionFailedError` with both the `@browser_string` and the message returned** from the Selenium RC if the response didn't start with "OK".  I also modified the `http_post` method to return the whole response body and the `method_missing` to return an array of return values for issuing get_X commands to the Selenium RC.

**Add this code to the code in the question** and you should be able to see which assertions fail on which browsers.

```
# Overrides a few Driver methods to make assertions return the
# browser string if they fail
module Selenium
  module Client
    class Driver
      def remote_control_command(verb, args=[])
        timeout(default_timeout_in_seconds) do
          status, response = http_post(http_request_for(verb, args))
          raise Test::Unit::AssertionFailedError.new("Browser:#{@browser_string} result:#{response}") if status != 'OK'
          return response[3..-1]
        end
      end

      def http_post(data)
        http = Net::HTTP.new(@server_host, @server_port)
        response = http.post('/selenium-server/driver/', data, HTTP_HEADERS)
        #return the first 2 characters and the entire response body
        [ response.body[0..1], response.body ]
      end
    end
  end
end

#Modify your method_missing to use seleniums.map to return the
#results of all the function calls as an array
class SeleniumTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def method_missing(method_name, *args)
    self.class.seleniums.map do |selenium_driver|
      selenium_driver.send(method_name, *args)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: Not a selenium expert.*

Do you just want to know which browser failed, or do you want to run the test across all browsers and then report the total failures when it's done?

The former is pretty simple if you store the drivers by hash in your setup. (I'm sure there's a fancy-pants way to do this with Hash.inject, but I'm lazy.)

```
@seleniums = {}
%w(*firefox *iexplore).each do |browser|
  puts 'creating browser ' + browser
  @seleniums[browser] = Selenium::SeleniumDriver.new("localhost", 4444, browser, "http://localhost:3003", 10000)
end
```

Then change your core function to modify exceptions to include the name of the driver being used, something like:

```
@seleniums.each do |name, driver|
  begin
    driver.send method_name, *args
  rescue Exception => ex
    raise ex.exception(ex.message + " (in #{name})")
  end
end
```

Should get you close.

Comment: Good idea, though failed tests don't necessarily throw exceptions I think.

Comment: Actually, they should always throw some kind of AssertionFailedException; but that Grid thing below looks mega-slick.

Answer (score 0):

you need to treat every test independently. So if one test fails it will carry on testing other tests. Check out [phpunit and selenium rc](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.4/en/selenium.html)