# Selenium RC:How to launch Interactive testing with Multiple browsers

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-rc

I want to automate this scenario. UserA assign an item to UserB, who gets an alert message. In order to do this I want to have two different browsers launched with different accounts to test this interaction.  Is is possible to do this? If yes, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like that question is already answered in my example code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/213430/selenium-rc-run-tests-in-multiple-browsers-automatically.

```
firefox = Selenium::SeleniumDriver.new("localhost", 4444, '*firefox', "http://localhost:3000", 10000)
ie = Selenium::SeleniumDriver.new("localhost", 4444, '*iexpore', "http://localhost:3000", 10000)
```

Then run the commands one the separate browsers how ever you'd like.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. That was so obvious.