# Running Test in Multiple Browsers using selenium-webdriver

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am currently using seleninium-webdriver for browser automation.  It launches firefox by default. How do i specify the browser and os combination to be used. is it through the **Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities** class , or should i use the appropriate driver for each case as in **Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome**  for **chrome** ?

Comment: Have you tried a search here on SO? See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/213430/selenium-rc-run-tests-in-multiple-browsers-automatically).

Answer (score 1):

you can choose, either with Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.[browser]
or by just specifying a hash with the browser/os/version you want:

```
capabilities = {
  :browserName => "firefox",
  :platform => "Windows"
}
```